# How to write a RegEx for finding name in email address?

Tags: regex

```
Kapil Arora <kapil.arora@abc.in>
```

How to find the name before angular bracket

This is the RegEx I used `([^<]+).` but it is not finding first String

Comment: SO is not a code writing service. Please show your effort and then ask if you are stuck somewhere.

Comment: sorry i forgot to add my regEx, anyway thank you for you valuable feedback

Comment: Try `(.*?)\s+<[^>]+` and extract string in first captured group.

Comment: how to find exactly the first match

Comment: What language/tool you're using?

Comment: i am using angularjs

Comment: `'Kapil Arora <kapil.arora@abc.in> '.match(/(.*?)\s+<[^>]+/)[1]`

Answer (score 0):

Since you haven't specified any language. I would be solving in JavaScript.

Lets assume an email id as "kapil.sharma123@gmail.com".

Thus the program would be something like this:

```
var email = "kapil.sharma123@gmail.com";
var regex = /(^[A-Za-z]+\.+[A-Za-z]+)/;
var res   = email.match(regex)[1];
res = res.split(".").join(" ");
```

Here I am matching the regex with the email id string and then extracting from the first index. 
Finally I am spliting on "." and joining with a blankspace.

Note : It also works for simple email ids like "kapil.sharma@gmail.com"

Answer (score 0):

I would just add a start of input anchor `^` to the head of your expression, plus a look ahead for a space so you get just the name (no trailing space):

```
^[^<]+(?= )
```

No need for brackets; group 0 is the whole match, which is what you want.

See [live demo](http://rubular.com/r/qymfHHl8fT).

Comment: but won't this capture leading spaces as well ?

Comment: @Riz yes it would, but the sample given in the question does have leading spaces.

Comment: I completely understand that, but as you were concerned about trailing space thus i thought it may be better to have the same for leading :)

Comment: @riz well there is a trailing space, and I'm a big believer in minimizing code.

Answer (score 0):

You may try this:

```js
const regex = /^\s*([^<]+)\s*</g;
const str = `Kapil Arora <kapil.arora@abc.in> bla bla bla <asadfasdf>`;
var match = regex.exec(str);
console.log(match[1].trim());
```